# characteristics of interface type dummy

Tags: rhel, interface

I've configured an interface 'nonlocal' with type dummy

```
ip link add nonlocal type dummy
```

on that interface are some IPv6 addresses configured. Now an apache can start with some ip based vhosts on above-said ipv6 addresses.

The "real" addresses get configured on the phyiscal interface if a second machine crashes (failover).  Everything works a expected.

But I would like to know the exact characteristics of such a dummy interface (on RHEL6 & 7). Is there a homepage or something similar which explains that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20220101000000*/http://www.pocketnix.org/posts/Linux%20Networking%3A%20Dummy%20Interfaces%20and%20Virtual%20Bridges) and according to [the source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/dummy.c), `dummy` interfaces appear to be kind of like the `/dev/null` of network interfaces. The interface will never receive a packet, and any packet you send to it goes nowhere. [Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6/source/drivers/net/dummy.c#L59)'s `dummy` transmit definition for kernel v6.6 which frees the buffer without doing much.

For your use case, you probably don't need a `dummy` interface at all. You can probably achieve what you need to binding the virtual IP address in question as a secondary IP address on the loopback interface (`lo`) as either a /32 (for IPv4) or /128 (for IPv6).

Comment: The lo interface will make a "network unreachable" entry in the routing table. The machine with the dummy device is the distributor of a Linux Virtual Server with DR. So the address must remain reachable.